# Uniquie Identifier check for ArcGIS REST Geocoded Data

Tags: mysql, database-design, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am querying the [ArcGIS Online REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/get-started-with-the-services-directory.htm) to [Geocode](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/geocode-service.htm) and normalise a address string the user enters into discrete data. An example of the normalised returned data:

```
VALID (RFC 8259)
Formatted JSON Data
{
   "spatialReference":{
      "wkid":102100,
      "latestWkid":3857
   },
   "candidates":[
      {
         "address":"12 Queen Street, Melbourne Central, Melbourne, 1010",
         "location":{
            "x":19454998.013352692,
            "y":-4417395.0764459781
         },
         "score":100,
         "attributes":{
            "Match_addr":"12 Queen Street, Melbourne Central, Melbourne, 1010",
            "Addr_type":"PointAddress",
            "StNumber: 12",
            "StName: Queen",
            "StType: Street",
            "StAddr":"12 Queen Street",
            "City":"Melbourne",
            "Country: AUS"
         },
         "extent":{
            "xmin":19454886.693861898,
            "ymin":-4417534.1797140706,
            "xmax":19455109.33284349,
            "ymax":-4417255.9749970241
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This GIS data is to be stored locally in a database with fields:

```
coords :POINT(X,Y)
match_addr: varchar
addr_type: varchar
st_addr: varchar
city: varchar
```

In future if the ArcGIS Geocoding API is again called and returns the same address I need a way to check my local database to make sure the same address does not already exist locally.

No UID is returned in the results and I can not use anything that relies on the coordinates as an apartment building may share the same coordinates, but be a different address.

Could I use the match address string to check for an existing entry in the local table, or is there a better way?

Comment: What would be stored for that data example?  Show a second example for a different location and one for the same "apartment building" but a different entity..